# The Coded UITest cannot be run as a 64 bit process

Tags: visual-studio-2012, x86-64, coded-ui-tests, ui-automation

I'm trying to create a UI automation using Visual Studio 2012 - Coded UI.
I've recorded the actions I want to perform (some basic Excel operations) and ran the test.
I got the following error:

```
Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  CodedUITestProject3.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject3\CodedUITestProject3\CodedUITest1.cs : line 27
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.1932062

Result Message: Error calling Initialization method for test class CodedUITestProject3.CodedUITest1: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: 
The Coded UITest cannot be run as a 64 bit process. You must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your test in a 32 bit process. For more information on creating test settings, 
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=246440&clcid=0x409.
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestExtensionExecution.BeforeTestInitialize(Object sender, BeforeTestInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunInitializeMethod()
```

I've tried changing the settings to x86 from the menu and creating a custom setting file from the help link, but it didn't work.
Any ideas on what should be done?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the [link listed in the error message](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=246440&clcid=0x409) ?

Comment: @CristiFati - Yes, I did. I've created the custom settings file and enabled it. It didn't help

Comment: Well... after lots and lots of digging, it seems that the root cause was that the machine I've ran the test on, was a VM. I'm not entirely sure it true, but once I've written the same test on a physical machine, it worked.

Comment: Could it be that the VM has a 32bit Windows, while the physical a 64bit one?

Comment: @cristifati, it is the case